# How to use Coq to prove a logical equivalence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Can anyone break down the following and show how to prove the following in Coq?

(q V p) ∧ (¬p -> q) <-> (p V q).

Here is what I started with in Coq:

```
Lemma work: (forall p q: Prop, (q \/ p)/\(~p -> q) <-> (p \/ q)).
Proof.
split.
intros H.
destruct H as [H1 H2].
```

Comment: Here's the answer to all your questions: use the `tauto` tactic.

Comment: How does that help me?

Comment: The tauto tactic lets Coq determine if your theorem is an intuitionistic tautology (which is a decidable problem) and defines it if so. (So Derek is making a joke, although you will certainly see pleasant greenery and “work is defined” if you simply write “tauto.” As your proof..) Based on your previous questions, I would start with learning what the “apply” tactic does.

Comment: (in this particular problem you don't really need apply till you get to the $\lnot p\to q$ part.)